# how to load a file locally and display its contents using html javascript without ajax?

Tags: javascript, html

i have the following to read a local file and display,

```
       <html>
       <head>
       <script> 
             function readfile() {
        document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.body.firstChild.innerHTML;
  }
     </script>
         </head>
        <body>
     <iframe id='iframe' src='txt2.txt' onload='readfile()'> </iframe>
     <input type="file" id="fileinput" />  
     </body>
    </html>
```

but here you can see i have already given the file path as 'txt2.txt', but i don't want to give the file name beforehand, instead i want to load the file and display its contents using input type="file", how to do this without using ajax ?

Comment: I don't think you can read a file locally.  Really, all you can do is POST a file to a web server.  Maybe some sort of HTML5, Flash, or Silverlight component could be used?

Comment: You can push the content as part of the web page itself, for example all the elements

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript, how to read local file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506518/javascript-how-to-read-local-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading local files from the browser is not allowed - This is to prevent websites reading files and stealing your information.

Please see the second post (answer) for more information:
[Javascript, how to read local file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506518/javascript-how-to-read-local-file)

> Being able to read a local file from your browser would be a major breach of security
>
> Most browsers will not let you read local files even if the page originated from your local filesystem.

You can however try the [HTML5 file API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Comment: Is that true even if the page is in the same local filesystem?

Answer (score 11):

The below code will browse a file and copy the content to a textarea:

```
   <input type="file" id="fileinput" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function readSingleFile(evt) {
        //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
        var f = evt.target.files[0]; 

        if (f) {
          var r = new FileReader();
          r.onload = function(e) { 
              var contents = e.target.result;
            alert( "Got the file.\n" 
                  +"name: " + f.name + "\n"
                  +"type: " + f.type + "\n"
                  +"size: " + f.size + " bytes\n"
                  + "starts with: " + contents.substr(1, contents.indexOf("\n"))
            );  
            document.getElementById('area').value=  contents;
          }
          r.readAsText(f);

        } else { 
          alert("Failed to load file");
        }
      }

      document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
    </script>

    <textarea rows=20 id="area"></textarea>
```